# Android UI slow on real phone but not in emulator

Tags: java, android, performance

new to the community of askers but have gotten countless answers from this resource.

I just started Android development in my spare time (known Java for a decade) and I have this app that has a problem I can't seem to figure out.

My UI is incredibly slow on my phone (LG G3) but in the emulator it runs buttery smooth. I have my code setup with the proper usages of async and off-ui threads for long-running code.

I have even disabled one of my settings switches to do absolutely nothing, and it is still very slow on my phone for the slider to move.

I'm thinking this might not be a code problem but as a novice I make no assumptions.

Here is my troubleshooting list thus far.

- Remove functionality from the switch I am testing with
- Add many debugging comments to see if there is a loop somewhere
- Uninstalled the app manually from my phone and re-installing with fresh settings

Anyhow here is the activity throwing lots of Choreographer warnings.
(Removed imports and variable declarations to save characters)

```java
  private void save() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke save()");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.SettingsLibraryName), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.showButtons), showButtons);
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.lightBackground), lightBackground);
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.enableNotifications), enableNotifications);
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.debugMode), debugMode);
    editor.putBoolean("enableSchedule", enableSchedule);
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.foregroundRefreshInterval), foregroundRefreshInterval);
    Log.d(TAG, "fri=" + String.valueOf(foregroundRefreshInterval));
    Log.d(TAG, "bri=" + String.valueOf(backgroundRefreshInterval));
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.backgroundRefreshInterval), backgroundRefreshInterval);
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.fri_seekPosition), fri_seekBarPosition);
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.bri_seekPosition), bri_seekBarPosition);
    editor.putInt("onImageIndex", selectedOnImage);
    editor.putInt("offImageIndex", selectedOffImage);
    editor.putInt("statusImageCounter", selectedImageSet);
    editor.putInt("toMonth", toMonth);
    editor.putInt("fromMonth", fromMonth);
    editor.apply();
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke onCreate()");

    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    loadSettings();
    Log.v(TAG, "showButtons: " + String.valueOf(showButtons) + " lightbackground: " + String.valueOf(lightBackground) + " notifications: " + String.valueOf(enableNotifications));
    //showButtons = ((MainActivity)ctx).showButtons;

    //lightBackground = ((MainActivity)ctx).lightBackground;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    //layoutId = R.layout.activity_settings;
    initializeObjects();
    configureObjects();
    startupObjectListeners();
    setDisplayColors();
    //Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(layoutId));
    Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(showButtons));

  }

  private void configureObjects() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke configureObjects()");
    offImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOffImage);
    lightBackgroundSwitch.setChecked(lightBackground);
    enableNotificationsSwitch.setChecked(enableNotifications);
    showButtonsSwitch.setChecked(!showButtons);
    onImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOnImage);
    debugSwitch.setChecked(debugMode);
    fri_seekBar.setProgress(fri_seekBarPosition);
    bri_seekBar.setProgress(bri_seekBarPosition);
    toMonth_seekBar.setProgress(toMonth - 1);
    fromMonth_seekBar.setProgress(fromMonth - 1);
    showMonth_Text(toMonth, toMonthSelectTitle, false);
    showMonth_Text(fromMonth, fromMonthSelectTitle, true);
    showFRI_Text(fri_seekBarPosition);
    showBRI_Text(bri_seekBarPosition);


    try {
      String versionString = "Version: " + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
      Log.d(TAG, getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName);
      Log.d(TAG, getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
      versionNumberTextBox.setText(versionString);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void loadSettings() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke loadSettings()");
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.SettingsLibraryName), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    showButtons = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.showButtons), true);
    lightBackground = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.lightBackground), false);
    enableNotifications = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.enableNotifications), true);
    debugMode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.debugMode), false);
    enableSchedule = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("enableSchedule", true);
    selectedOnImage = sharedPreferences.getInt("onImageIndex", R.drawable.power_on_image_1);
    selectedOffImage = sharedPreferences.getInt("offImageIndex", R.drawable.power_off_image_1);
    selectedImageSet = sharedPreferences.getInt("statusImageCounter", 1);
    toMonth = sharedPreferences.getInt("toMonth", 1);
    fromMonth = sharedPreferences.getInt("fromMonth", 1);
    foregroundRefreshInterval = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.foregroundRefreshInterval), 0);
    backgroundRefreshInterval = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.backgroundRefreshInterval), 0);
    fri_seekBarPosition = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.fri_seekPosition), 0);
    bri_seekBarPosition = sharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.bri_seekPosition), 0);


  }

  private void initializeObjects() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke initializeObjects()");
    showButtonsSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.showButtonsSwitch);
    fromMonth_seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.fromMonth_seekBar);
    toMonth_seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.toMonth_seekBar);
    fri_seekBarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fri_Text);
    bri_seekBarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bri_Text);
    fri_seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.fri);
    bri_seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.bri);
    lightBackgroundSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.lightBackgroundSwitch);
    enableNotificationsSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.enableNotificationsSwitch);
    enableScheduleSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.enableSchedule);
    debugSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.debugMode);
    displaySettingsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaySettingsTitle);
    imageSetTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageSetTitle);
    rightArrow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightArrow);
    leftArrow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leftArrow);
    systemSettingsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemSettingsTitle);
    versionNumberTextBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.versionNumber);
    fromMonthSelectTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromMonthSelectionTitle);
    summerMonthsTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summerMonthsTitle);
    summerHoursTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summerHoursTitle);
    toMonthSelectTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toMonthSelectionTitle);
    onImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.onImagePreview);
    offImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.offImagePreview);
    previewContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewContainer);

  }

  private void startupObjectListeners() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke startupObjectListeners()");

    fri_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        showFRI_Text(progress);
      }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });

    bri_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        showBRI_Text(progress);
      }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });

    fromMonth_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        fromMonth = progress + 1;
        showMonth_Text(progress + 1, fromMonthSelectTitle, true);
      }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });

    toMonth_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        toMonth = progress + 1;
        showMonth_Text(progress + 1, toMonthSelectTitle, false);
      }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });


    previewContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
      @Override
      public void onSwipeRight() {
        previousImage();
      }

      public void onSwipeLeft() {
        nextImage();
      }
    });


  }

  private void showMonth_Text(int month, TextView target, boolean from) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke showMonth_Text()");

    if (from) {
      switch (month) {
        case 1:
          target.setText("From: January");
          break;
        case 2:
          target.setText("From: February");
          break;
        case 3:
          target.setText("From: March");
          break;
        case 4:
          target.setText("From: April");
          break;
        case 5:
          target.setText("From: May");
          break;
        case 6:
          target.setText("From: June");
          break;
        case 7:
          target.setText("From: July");
          break;
        case 8:
          target.setText("From: August");
          break;
        case 9:
          target.setText("From: September");
          break;
        case 10:
          target.setText("From: October");
          break;
        case 11:
          target.setText("From: November");
          break;
        case 12:
          target.setText("From: Decemeber");
          break;
      }
    } else {
      switch (month) {
        case 1:
          target.setText("To: January");
          break;
        case 2:
          target.setText("To: February");
          break;
        case 3:
          target.setText("To: March");
          break;
        case 4:
          target.setText("To: April");
          break;
        case 5:
          target.setText("To: May");
          break;
        case 6:
          target.setText("To: June");
          break;
        case 7:
          target.setText("To: July");
          break;
        case 8:
          target.setText("To: August");
          break;
        case 9:
          target.setText("To: September");
          break;
        case 10:
          target.setText("To: October");
          break;
        case 11:
          target.setText("To: November");
          break;
        case 12:
          target.setText("To: Decemeber");
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  public void toggleSchedule(View v) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke toggleSchedule()");

    enableSchedule = !enableSchedule;
    if (fromMonthSelectTitle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      fromMonthSelectTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      fromMonthSelectTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (toMonthSelectTitle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      toMonthSelectTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      toMonthSelectTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (fromMonth_seekBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      fromMonth_seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      fromMonth_seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (summerMonthsTitle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      summerMonthsTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      summerMonthsTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (summerHoursTitle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      summerHoursTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
      summerHoursTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

  }

  private void showFRI_Text(int progress) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke showFRI_Text()");
    //float weightedProgress=((300000.0f)/(-1*(progress-3681.63467f)))-81.486f;
    fri_seekBarPosition = progress;
    //progress = ((int) weightedProgress);
    progress = progress / 60;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = progress;
    int hours = 0;
    if (progress > 59) {
      minutes = progress / 60;
      if (minutes > 59) {
        hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;
      }
      seconds = progress % 60;
    }

    String message = getString(R.string.fri_text);
    if (hours != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(hours) + " Hours " + String.valueOf(minutes) + " Minutes";
    } else if (minutes != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(minutes) + " Minutes";
    } else if (seconds != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(seconds) + " Seconds";
    } else {
      message = message + " Never";
    }
    foregroundRefreshInterval = progress;
    fri_seekBarText.setText(message);
  }

  private int getStatusImageCount(String searchString) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke getStatusImageCount()");

    int count = 0;
    Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    List < Integer > drawables = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
    for (Field field: fields) {
      // Take only those with name starting with "fr"
      if (field.getName().startsWith(searchString)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }


  private void showBRI_Text(int progress) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Invoke showBRI_Text()");

    float weightedProgress = ((50000000.0 f) / (-1 * (progress - 23710.0 f))) - 2108.815 f;
    // Log.d(TAG,"weightedProgress="+String.valueOf(weightedProgress));
    bri_seekBarPosition = progress;
    progress = ((int) weightedProgress);
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = progress;
    int hours = 0;
    if (progress > 59) {
      minutes = progress / 60;
      if (minutes > 59) {
        hours = minutes / 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;
      }
      seconds = progress % 60;
    }

    String message = getString(R.string.bri_text);
    if (hours != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(hours) + " Hours " + String.valueOf(minutes) + " Minutes";
    } else if (minutes != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(minutes) + " Minutes";
    } else if (seconds != 0) {
      message = message + String.valueOf(seconds) + " Seconds";
    } else {
      message = message + " Never";
    }
    backgroundRefreshInterval = progress;
    bri_seekBarText.setText(message);
  }


  public void playButtonTickSound() {
    SoundInterface.SoundRunnable sound = new SoundInterface.SoundRunnable(this, "tick");
    sound.run();

  }

  public void toggleShowButtons(View v) {
    //playButtonTickSound();
    showButtons = !showButtons;

    //Log.v(TAG, showButtons.toString());
  }

  public void toggleDebugMode(View v) {
    //playButtonTickSound();
    debugMode = !debugMode;

    //Log.v(TAG, showButtons.toString());
  }

  public void toggleNotifications(View v) {
    //playButtonTickSound();
    enableNotifications = !enableNotifications;

    //Log.v(TAG, enableNotifications.toString());
  }


  public void toggleBackground(View v) {
    //playButtonTickSound();
    //lightBackground = !lightBackground;

    //setDisplayColors();
    //Log.v(TAG, showButtons.toString());
  }


  public void nextImage(View v) {
    nextImage();

  }

  public void nextImage() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Next Image");
    int totalImages = getStatusImageCount("power_on_");
    Log.v(TAG, "Total Images = " + String.valueOf(totalImages));
    Log.v(TAG, "counter = " + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet));
    if (selectedImageSet < totalImages) {
      selectedImageSet++;
    } else {
      selectedImageSet = 1;
    }
    String onImageName = "power_on_image_" + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet);
    String offImageName = "power_off_image_" + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet);

    selectedOnImage = getResources().getIdentifier(onImageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    selectedOffImage = getResources().getIdentifier(offImageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    Log.d(TAG, "selectedOnImage ID=" + String.valueOf(selectedOnImage));
    Log.d(TAG, "selectedOffImage ID=" + String.valueOf(selectedOffImage));
    onImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOnImage);
    offImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOffImage);

  }

  public void previousImage(View v) {
    previousImage();

  }

  public void previousImage() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Next Image");
    int totalImages = getStatusImageCount("power_on_");
    Log.v(TAG, "Total Images = " + String.valueOf(totalImages));
    Log.v(TAG, "counter = " + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet));
    if (selectedImageSet > 1) {
      selectedImageSet--;
    } else {
      selectedImageSet = totalImages;
    }
    String onImageName = "power_on_image_" + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet);
    String offImageName = "power_off_image_" + String.valueOf(selectedImageSet);

    selectedOnImage = getResources().getIdentifier(onImageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    selectedOffImage = getResources().getIdentifier(offImageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    Log.d(TAG, "selectedOnImage ID=" + String.valueOf(selectedOnImage));
    Log.d(TAG, "selectedOffImage ID=" + String.valueOf(selectedOffImage));
    onImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOnImage);
    offImagePreview.setImageResource(selectedOffImage);

  }

  private void setDisplayColors() {
    /*
    if (lightBackground) {
        findViewById(R.id.settings_container).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        showButtonsSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        lightBackgroundSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        enableNotificationsSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        versionNumberTextBox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        displaySettingsTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        systemSettingsTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        debugSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        fri_seekBarText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        bri_seekBarText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        leftArrow.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        rightArrow.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        imageSetTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        fromMonthSelectTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        toMonthSelectTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        enableScheduleSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.settings_container).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        showButtonsSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        lightBackgroundSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        enableNotificationsSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        displaySettingsTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        systemSettingsTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        debugSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        fri_seekBarText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        bri_seekBarText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        rightArrow.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        leftArrow.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        imageSetTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        fromMonthSelectTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        toMonthSelectTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        enableScheduleSwitch.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        versionNumberTextBox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    */
  }


  public void exitSettings(View v) {
    exitSettings();
  }

  public void exitSettings() {
    save();
    //playButtonTickSound();
    Log.v(TAG, "showButtons: " + String.valueOf(showButtons) + " lightbackground: " + String.valueOf(lightBackground) + " notifications: " + String.valueOf(enableNotifications));
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    //myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myIntent.putExtra("tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol.MainActivity", true);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    //super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //layoutId = R.layout.activity_main;
    // Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(layoutId));
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    exitSettings();
    // your code.
  }


}
```

And the logcat. I go to my settings activity at the start of the log and I hit my test switch at the moment the Choreographer warnings start.

```raw
05-02 18:00:14.824 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke onCreate()
05-02 18:00:14.824 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke loadSettings()
05-02 18:00:14.824 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: showButtons: false lightbackground: true notifications: true
05-02 18:00:14.878 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke initializeObjects()
05-02 18:00:14.878 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke configureObjects()
05-02 18:00:14.880 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke showMonth_Text()
05-02 18:00:14.880 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke showMonth_Text()
05-02 18:00:14.880 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke showFRI_Text()
05-02 18:00:14.880 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke showBRI_Text()
05-02 18:00:14.881 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol D/SettingsActivity: tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol
05-02 18:00:14.882 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol D/SettingsActivity: 1.45
05-02 18:00:14.882 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: Invoke startupObjectListeners()
05-02 18:00:14.882 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/SettingsActivity: false
05-02 18:00:14.950 31627-32222/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol D/MainActivity: 2017/05/02 15:32:27
05-02 18:00:14.952 31627-32222/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/MainActivity: It is not summer the current month is 4
05-02 18:00:14.953 31627-32222/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol V/MainActivity: Completed background schedueld task
05-02 18:00:16.175 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:17.283 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:18.571 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:19.723 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:20.559 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:21.564 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:22.338 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:23.281 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:24.031 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:25.134 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:31.340 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:32.389 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-02 18:00:33.211 31627-31627/tk.jacobsen.chris.vapecontrol I/Choreographer: Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: I was using toggleBackground as my test switch

Comment: Use [method tracing](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html) to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like it might do the trick.